# .htaccess error on document root mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, configuration

OK, so, I am getting a problem with `.htaccess`.

Let's say I can visit a profile doing this: `http://website.com/members.php?id=1`

So, then I want to `mod_rewrite` it by going here: `http://website.com/1`

So I add this to my `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /members.php?id=$1 [L]
```

I visit `http://website.com/1`. It doesn't work. In fact, I get a `500` error.

So, I decide to try something else. I add a prefix `user/` in front. So it becomes this:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)$ /members.php?id=$1 [L]
```

See the new **user/**?

I visit `http://website.com/user/1`. It works. Weird.

Help? Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line before your RewriteRule to prevent looping:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
```

Comment: So. like this? http://codepad.org/5bhecEgH Cause that's not working... I am still getting redirect loop

Comment: First `RewriteCond` in your code is redundant, I reworked it here: http://codepad.org/MgagrnQb

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because your rule suffers from recursion. Your rule also catches and rewrites `members.php`...

Comment: But.. I don't know what to do... I've seen other sites have a rule like that... how do they do it?

Answer (score 1):

Add this in front of your rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/members.php
```

Comment: I get this error when I leave members.php `This webpage has a redirect loop`